# Dynamic Drop List for Many to Many relation

Tags: django, drop-down-menu, dynamic-data-list

I have 2 tables "Client" and "Location".

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

A Client can be in many Locations and a Location can have many Clients.

I created a third table to hold this relationship:

```
class Client_Location(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I created a form to test whether i can make the dropdownlist dynamic, so if i were to pick a client, any location linked to that client would only appear.

```
class ClientLocationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Client_Location
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['location'].queryset = Location.objects.none()
```

So far i was only able to make the location field blank. Not sure where to go next as examples i've seen aren't exactly like mine.

Comment: In general I would suggest use `models.ManyToManyField` then we can achieve this easily. And other things you can manage through ajax

Comment: So would i use client = models.ManyToManyField(Location)? I have not used ajax before, how would i go about doing that? @AnupYadav

Answer (score 0):

With minimal changes to your code, you may add the existing `Client_Location` model as `through` model for a new explicit `ManyToMany` relationship. To do so, add the following field to your `Client` model:

```
 locations = models.ManyToManyField('Location', through='Client_Location', related_name='clients')
```

If you need fully dynamic updates, you need to write a view which provides a list of locations for a specified client (`client.locations.all()`) and then show them on your page.

Comment: Would this alone make the drop down list dynamic? All my locations are stored in a table in postgresql

Comment: @Lloyd, to make dropdown dynamic (when on page you choose client, all locations load without page reload), you indeed need to write Ajax script on your site, which makes request to a view that returns needed locations.

Comment: Would you be able to show me how the ajax code is suppose to look like?

Comment: @Lloyd, that's quite a different question :)